# UML, HLD and LLD examples

Tags: uml

i need some clarification on UML documentation

1. what is UML
2. how UML different from HLD and LLD.
3. sample diagram for UML,HLD and LLD.

Comment: yes i tried. i don't have proper example for this.

Answer (score 3):

UML is a standard language for specifying, visualizing, constructing, and documenting the artifacts of software systems. Here is a [Complete understanding of UML](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/).

A perfect explanation of High/Low Level design is a duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356801/software-engineering-hld-and-lld).